# Android GET_ACCOUNTS Permission Added Automatically

Tags: android, android-permissions

I've seen a few questions about this, but the responses all refer to Android Studio and none have helped me. I'm still using Eclipse for my project so I am looking for an answer for Eclipse.

After doing some updates to my app, all of a sudden Google is injecting the GET_ACCOUNTS permission. The updates were simply a few code changes, increasing the minSdkVersion to 16, and updating the Google licensing library. I only use one external library in the app and it's the Google licensing library. My manifest is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mycompany.myproduct_app" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionName="1.52" android:versionCode="15200">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="22"></uses-sdk>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- Required permission to check licensing. -->    
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|navigation"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Is it possible that the updated Google licensing code is adding this permission, or that there could be an API call I'm making that could be doing it? I never request the user's e-mail, or have any login routines like Google+. Google's licensing library manifest is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.google.android.vending.licensing"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.5">
<!-- Devices >= 3 have version of Android Market that supports licensing. -- >
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<!-- Required permission to check licensing. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
</manifest>
```

After uploading to the Play Store customers are asking why the GET_ACCOUNTS permission is there. If anyone knows where this is coming from it would be greatly appreciated. Again, please restrict your answers to Eclipse, if it matters.

Thanks!